# can we display thows datatable rows that are matching with mysql like operator using ajax and laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

```
public function search(Request $request){
    $search=array();
            $new_customer=New_Customer_M::orderByDesc('id')->where('first_name','like','%'.$request->search.'%')->get();
            foreach($new_customer as $cutomer_name){
                $search[]=array(
                    'first_name'=>$new_customer,
                );
            }
        return response()->json($search);
    }
```

this is code for fecth data from database but how we write code in ajax to all disaply rows that are matching with all json data

Comment: It depends on your architecture, but you have to define a route (usually in web.php) and then you can access that route using axios or fetch. Can you show us your web.php and the javascript you've writtent?

Comment: Route::get('new_customer/search','New_Customer@search')->name('new_customer.search');

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#search').on('keyup', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '{{route("new_customer.search")}}',
    type: 'get',
    data:{ search:$(this).val() },
    dataType: 'json',
  }).done(function(res) {
    $.each(res, function(key, val) {
      table.column(2).search(val).draw();
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: you have solution for this qution sir.i am share route  and javascript code also

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solves the problem.